# ESLint failing on relative imports with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

I have been trying to get eslint working in an existing project, following the airbnb style guide. I have most of it working, but I can't get the relative imports that I use to pass linting. an example of one of my relative imports is:

`import { actions as practiceActions } from 'reducers/practice';`

which give the following linting error.

`Unable to resolve path to module 'reducers/practice'`

my .eslintrc.json is as follows:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "mocha": true
    },
    "extends": ["airbnb-base"],
    "globals": {
        "spy": true,
        "stub": true,
        "mount": true,
        "shallow": true,
        "chai": true,
        "expect": true,
        "sinon": true,
        "getStoreAction": true,
        "getMockStore": true,
        "render": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "semi": 2,
        "max-len": [1, 100, 2],
        "indent": ["error", 4],
        "import/extensions": ["warn", "never"],
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
        "react/jsx-uses-react": "error"
    },
    "settings" : {
        "import/extensions": ["js", "jsx", "png"],
        "import/resolver": { //note that I have also tried just using "webpack" as the resolver, with the same outcome.
            "node": {
                "extensions": [".js",".jsx"]
            }
        }, 
        "import/ignore": ["node_modules", ".(scss|less|css)$"]
    }
}
```

My webpack config is quite long, but it's the default from create react app. There have been no manual changes to this.

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: [
        require.resolve('./polyfills'),
        require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
        paths.appIndexJs,
    ],
    output: {
        pathinfo: true,
        filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
        publicPath: publicPath,
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
            path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
            process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean),
        ),
        extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        },
        plugins: [
            new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
        ],
    },
    module: {
        strictExportPresence: true,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                use: [
                    {
                        options: {
                            formatter: eslintFormatter,
                            eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

                        },
                        loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
                    },
                ],
                include: paths.appSrc,
            },
            {
                oneOf: [
                    {
                        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
                        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
                        options: {
                            limit: 10000,
                            name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                    // Process JS with Babel.
                    {
                        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
                        include: paths.appSrc,
                        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                        options: {
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.module.css$/,
                        use: [
                            require.resolve('style-loader'),
                            {
                                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                                options: {
                                    importLoaders: 1,
                                    modules: true,
                                    localIdentName: '[path]__[name]___[local]',
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                                options: {
                                    ident: 'postcss',
                                    plugins: () => [
                                        require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                                        autoprefixer({
                                            browsers: [
                                                '>1%',
                                                'last 4 versions',
                                                'Firefox ESR',
                                                'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                                            ],
                                            flexbox: 'no-2009',
                                        }),
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.css$/,
                        exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
                        use: [
                            require.resolve('style-loader'),
                            {
                                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                                options: {
                                    importLoaders: 1,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                                options: {
                                    ident: 'postcss',
                                    plugins: () => [
                                        require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                                        autoprefixer({
                                            browsers: [
                                                '>1%',
                                                'last 4 versions',
                                                'Firefox ESR',
                                                'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                                            ],
                                            flexbox: 'no-2009',
                                        }),
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
                        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                        options: {
                            name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    ],
    node: {
        dgram: 'empty',
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
        child_process: 'empty',
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
```

Everything else seems to work fine linting-wise, and the relative imports are working in the application. I just can't get them to be recognized by my linter.

Comment: Have you tried to change the path like
`import { actions as practiceActions } from './reducers/practice';` ?

Comment: ya you either need the ./ or just a / in front of the import

Comment: Just did, and that didn't work. for more information, the actual path from the root of the project would be /src/reducers/practice. Also, it's best practice (according to airbnb) to not use absolute paths as you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a further look at the docs for `eslint-plugin-imports` [webpack resolver](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/tree/master/resolvers/webpack). Specifically, try passing the location of your webpack config explicitly in `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
    // ...
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "webpack": {
                "config": "my.webpack.config.js"
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hopefully that causes the resolver to pick up all `resolve` options in the webpack config.